# Django nested query in From clause

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any way to construct a query like the following using Django ORM?

```
SELECT * from ( SELECT r1 from table_name ) temp;
```

Comment: It makes no sense to try to "translate" SQL to Django. Explain *what* you aim to do, not how you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) as the docs says.

Here is an example:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery


Table.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(Table2.objects.filter(...).values_list("table_id", flat=True)))
```

Comment: If I am not this will nest query if WHERE clause,like the following:

SELECT table_id from Table where id in ( SELECT id from Table2 where ... );
I am looking to nest query in FROM clause not WHERE clause.